# Tinder Laravel matching between 2 models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, tinder

i have 2 tables namely users and employers . I would like to match them together like tinder style, which means that when both the user and the employer liked each other , they will each receive a notification .

However i am not sure how would the `relationship` table will look like??

Right now what i have is in the `Relationship` Table ,

1.`user_id`

2.`target_employer_id`

3.`employer_id`

4.`target_user_id`

If i am not wrong , this is considered as a Many - Many relationship. 
So , is this table correct???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, in your application, a user can like an employer, and an employer can like a user.

If this is right, it seems clear to me that there are two distinct (many to many) relationships (user => employer, employer => user), and that in your proposed table only two fields are filled at a time.

The best way to represent those relationships is to use two tables.

User to employer fields:

1. user_id
2. target_employer_id

Employer to user fields:

1. employer_id
2. target_user_id

Depending if you are using Laravel 4 or Laravel 5, you can use one of those two packages to generate the two pivot tables via a migration:

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. But how would i check if they are both liked each other? like they are a matched?

Comment: It depends in which context you are looking for the information.

Comment: What if I want them to set a meeting date ? Does that mean I need another table called "Meetings" ? And if it is, the column would be something like user_id, employer_id and date ?

Comment: It depends in which context you are looking for the information.
If for example you are asking, in the point of view of a user, with which employer the relation is mutual, you can do something like the following query (not tested):

`SELECT employer_id FROM UserEmployer UE JOIN EmployerUser EU ON UE.employer_id = EU.employer_id AND UE.user_id = EU.user_id WHERE UE.user_id = 123`

And yes, for the meeting, it is definitely another kind of object that should be stored in a different table.

Comment: Okay. I think I roughly get what you are trying to say. Lemme try it out first . thanks again